# Anyone have a bit of script to disable the submit button after it's pressed

Tags: php, html

Can anyone tell me how to disable the submit button after it has been pressed 20 times?
The `HTML` runs like this: `<input type=submit name='sub' value='submit' onClick='this.disabled=true;return true;doSection(loading);'>` and this code `<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" disabled /></p>` What should I do so that after pressing the button 20 times, it is dsabled?

Comment: Does the number of times it has been pressed need to be remembered after a page reload ?

Comment: The submit button does not necesarily result in page load. Perhaps he has intercepted the default behavior somewhere else and is doing something different..

Comment: Can you post all the relevant code, including the `<form ...>` markup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a counter that gets updated with every click on the button, when the counter has reached 20, disable it:

```
count = 0;
button = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0] 
/*assuming it's the only submit button in the page */
button.onclick = function() {
 count++;
 if (count == 20) {
   this.disabled = true;
 }
};
```

Comment: <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" disabled /></p> can u make it for now for 20 times submit then disable the button

Comment: Umm, isn't that what this code is doing?

Comment: I think he means that he is submitting a form, rather than just clicking on a button. No answers seem to take it into account yet.

Comment: If he is indeed submitting a form, then the page will reload, and the count will be lost..

Comment: this is possible that button permanent disable after 20 time pressing

Comment: means after permanent disable the button user can't again submit button if he reload the page or submit form after some hours but button are permanent disable

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/X7Y7W/1/

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<p>Click the button to trigger a function.</p>

<button id="demo">Click me</button>

</body>

<script>
var nbSubmits = 0;
document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function (){
    nbSubmits++;
    if(nbSubmits == 20) {
        document.getElementById("demo").disabled="true";
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: u make it rite but here is i press 1 time then button is disable in first time pressing i need after 20 time pressing the button then button are disable

Comment: @user2597055 see edits,

Comment: @user2597055 making some effort won't kill you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
var NumberOfClicks = 0;
function disbale(thisobject)
{
NumberOfClicks++;
    if(NumberOfClicks == 2){
        thisobject.disabled="true";
    }
}
</script>

<button id="demo" onclick="disbale(this)">Click me</button>
```

Comment: if anyone reload the page then button are again enable this is possible that after 20 times pressing the button .... button are disable permanent if any one can reload the page so he cant push the button

Comment: @user2597055: you need to set cookie! or HTML5 storage

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `return true;doSection(loading);`, I suspect doSection will never get executed. Put the `return true;` in last position.

Also please note that a submit button is supposed to submit the fields of its parent form. So you should be redirected to another page (or the same). Which means if you use javascript to count the click number, the counter will get reset after the first submit.